# Sparrow Toolkit CandleStick chart in C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I've found the sparrow toolkit for drawing candlestick charts.
However, i'm not finding much documentation about how to use this.
Has anybodyelse experience in this? I'm using C# and WPF.

A great example would really be welcome.

Sincerely,

J